# Maximum value of column in matrix?

Tags: for-loop, matrix, max

How can i find the maximum value of a column in a matrix using only 2 for's in Java?

```
for(int i = 1; i< N; i++)
    for(int j = 1; j < M; j++)
         i want to find the maxim for each column
```

Comment: Why do you need 2 for loops to find max in a column?

Comment: How else I can do that?

Comment: Maybe he means the maximum value in any column?

Comment: To find the maximum value in a *particular* column, only one loop is required - loop over each value in *that* column. Two loops could find the maximum value in the matrix. That is, I suspect "maximum value of a column" is incorrect wording that should be changed - explain the pseudo-algorithm below.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int findMaxInCol(int colIndex){
  int max = Integer.Min;
  for(int row=0;row<Matrix.Rows;row++){

    if(matrix[row][colIndex] > max){
       max = matrix[row]colIndex];
   }

}
   return max;
}



void int findMaxOfMaxes() {
   int maxOfMaxs = Integer.min;
   for(int col=0;col<j;col++){
      int maxInCol = findMaxInCol(col);
      if( maxInCol > maxOfMaxs)
          maxOfMaxs = maxInCol;
    }
    return maxOfMaxs 

}
```

//pseudocode

//editing after finding that you wanted max in a matrix. You are right, you need 2 for loops.

Comment: It's possible to do with only 1, but ugly.  You only would if someone specifically told you "you can only use one for loop", and then it basically involves iterating over the index and decomposing the index into row and column via / and % respectively.

Comment: It also depends on how is your matrix defined. For example, if it is defined as a dynamic array, then one loop is enough:  'for(int i = 0; i < N*M; ++i)'  .